# Sluggish step response of control loop

Tags: control, control-system

I have a question regarding the PI controller.
Lets say I have an actuator via which I control
some plant. The control signal at the output of
the PI controller is at its maximal realizable 
value. So the actuator supplies 100% power
into the plant. Despite this fact the time 
response of the control loop is sluggish. Does
it mean that the actuator has been chosen in
wrong manner for a given plant? 
Thanks for clarification.

Comment: If ignoring only the time response (related to I), wouldn't it also be possible that the gain (related to P) was incorrectly chosen for the type of actuator?

Comment: @Nedd the control signal is at its maximal value very quickly. So it seems to me that the controller gains are tuned correctly.

Comment: It may still be possible that the actuator is chosen incorrectly. However, consider for example if P=100, maximal actuator input is 100, and the feedback range is 1 to 100.  The actuator will always be at maximum. (Also consider that some systems may require a P <1 or even a -P.)

Comment: @L3sek, If I understand correctly, you could simply replace your PI controller for a step input and the response would still be slow, correct? Thus the problem has nothing to do with the control loop, but with how your system responds to your actuator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the control signal is at maximum and you are still not getting the system performance you want than the problem would be an under sized actuator.

Consider a controls engineer sitting in their car at a stop light that just turned green.  The engineer would like to reach a speed of 40 Mph as soon as possible.  So the engineer floors the peddle.  You can consider a floored peddle a saturated command signal.  At this point it is no longer up to the engineer to affect the acceleration of the vehicle.  The only way to improve the cars performance is by changing the car it self.  Not the control system (The driver in this case)

Comment: thank you for your answer. Lets say I have two actuators. One of them is underrated and the other one is more powerful. I also have a way how to switch from the underrated to the more powerful one. Is there any algorithm for determining the switching instant? For example control error greater than some threshold for some time along with control signal at its maximum value?

Comment: @L3sek Off hand I do not know.  It sounds like you have got a good idea where to start.  If this is in regards to a real system would there be a reason to keep both actuators and not simply use the larger one alone?

Comment: I meant for example a battery charger with limited discharging current. This battery charger can be bypassed via parallel contactor.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean that the actuator has been chosen in wrong manner for a
>   given plant?

If the actuator is at a point where it cant give additional energy its called a saturation point. Saturation points are bad because:

- it makes the system hard to analyze because it no longer behaves linearly.
- it can make the system unstable because of integrator windup and other effects (the system is not longer linear).

A change to the system would need to be made to prevent saturation of the actuator which could be done by changing the gain or increasing the actuator so it can respond with more energy.